# How to I prevent vscode from opening while running a file in startup

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, startup

**Hi**

I made a simple app to always run on start up.

Here is the script:

```
import os
import webbrowser
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Canvas

wifiURL = 'https://168.1.254:8090/httpclient.html'
chromePath = 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome.exe'

def PlayGame():
    os.startfile("C:\Customization\Games shortkuts")

def MakeGames():
    os.startfile("C:\Customization\Gamedev shortkuts")

def LoginWIFI():
    webbrowser.get('C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google 
Chrome.exe %s').open(wifiURL)


root = tk.Tk()

Canvas = tk.Canvas(root,bg="Gray")
Canvas.pack()

Login = tk.Button(Canvas, text="Login", padx= 50, pady=0.8, command=LoginWIFI)
Login.pack()

PlayGames = tk.Button(Canvas, text="Play Games", padx=50,pady=0.8,command=PlayGame)
PlayGames.pack()

GameDev = tk.Button(Canvas, text="Game development", padx=50,pady=0.8,command=MakeGames)
GameDev.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

To run it every time on startup I made a shortcut and copied it to the startup folder .

But every time I open my computer, instead of running the program it opens vscode.
To prevent that I changed the default application for `.py` files to python.exe but it is still showing the same behaviour.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the file, select "open with", select "choose another app" at the bottom, select "Python", and check "always use this app" at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

if python is installed in C:\python and your script is C:\pythonscripts\myscript.py, create a shortcut running

```
C:\Python\python.exe C:\pythonscripts\myscript.py
```

And place the shortcut in your startup folder